# How to check if property is defined and provide a substitute in PHP?

Tags: php, object, isset

My service sometimes returns

```
$business->price
```

set and sometimes not and my code

```
$feature['properties']['price'] = $business->price;
```

throws error

```
Undefined property: stdClass::$price'
```

in that case.

What is the shortest way to check if property set and if it is, then return it's value, but if it isn't then return some predefined value like `0` or `NULL`?

Comment: `$feature['properties']['price'] = (isset($business->price) ? $business->price : 'some_default');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ternary operator,if it`s not set the price will be 0

```
$feature['properties']['price'] = $business->price ? $business->price : 0;
```

Comment: Won't this still display the `undefined property ` message?

Answer (score 1):

It is always safe to use ternary operators in php. Here is an example,

```
$retVal = (condition) ? a : b ;
```

in your case as @hassan already stated,

```
$feature['properties']['price'] = (isset($business->price) ? $business->price : 'some_default');
```

But, the biggest error here is how your code handles Classes. Before you try to use the isset function, first you should try to avoid getting an error at the first place. I think your code may not be well-constructed.